# How to run a stored procedure in sql server every hour?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cron

I have a table on which I want to perform some operations every hour. For this I created a Stored Procedure but don't know how to call it every hour. I know there are some kind of scheduled jobs, but how to use them.

Is there some kind of service also that keeps on running continuously, every second, where I can place my piece of code to be executed ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In SSMS navigate to SQL Server Agent-->Jobs
Right click on the Job Folder and select new job

on the dialog that pops up, give the job a name
click on steps, then on new, you will see a dialog like the following, pick correct DB and type your proc name

[image]

after that click on schedule, pick new and you will see something like the image below, fill all the stuff you need and click ok, click ok on the job and you should be set
[image]

Comment: imgur embedding is squirrelly now, but in case it's useful to others, I can access the images directly at http://i.imgur.com/Woxpv.png and http://i.imgur.com/tSUau.png

Comment: And If you need to send notification email to someone (let's say WebMaster) based on the sp result, In Job Step:  
`DECLARE @result bit` --assuming YourProc output is bit.   
`Exec YourProc @spResult = @result OUTPUT` and then  
`if(@result = 0)  
Begin  
        DECLARE @subject nvarchar(max) = 'Notification!'  
        DECLARE @body nvarchar(max) = 'Something went wrong... '  
        DECLARE @to nvarchar(max) = 'WebMaster@Somewhere.com'  
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @to, @subject = @subject, @body = @body;  
End`

Comment: I tried this kind of scenario, but I was lil bit confused why it doesn't execute the next day. The same settings and all especially the settings on daily frequency.

Comment: SQL Server Agent is located near the very bottom, below Management, and will only be available for those with the role Sysadmin on a non-Express version of SQL Server Management Studio. In later versions you must click on Steps to enter your procedure name.

Answer (score 4):

1) Use the SQL Server Agent (open MS Management Studio)
2) New Job
3) Add Step
4) Choose Transact SQL
5) EXEC MyStroredProc
6) Choose database
7) Add schedule
8) Occurs every hour

**Add notification to know that process is doing well (or bad).**

**In the properties of SQL Server Agent check that all Auto restart options are switch ON**

Answer (score 0):

Set up a SQL Server agent job to execute the stored procedure at 1 hour intervals