# SQL Server Azure - Executing stored procedure every x minutes

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

Generally with SQL Server, I could setup a job and have it run every so often. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348863/how-to-run-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-every-hour). However SQL Server Azure does not seem to have this ability.

My thoughts were to instead, have a service that runs this procedure every x minutes. I'm just wondering if anyone sees any issues with that, or has any better suggestions?

The stored procedure takes some xml data stored in one table and normalizes it across other tables making it easier to query on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule jobs using the new Scheduler:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/21/great-updates-to-windows-azure-mobile-services-web-sites-sql-data-sync-acs-media-more.aspx

More Detail:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/schedule-backend-tasks/

Comment: It seems this is tightly coupled to Mobile Services. Why? Are there limitations there? Seems interesting but also seems retarded to tie this directly to Mobile Services in any way...

Comment: I agree with @Jaxidian that it seems odd its tied into Mobile Services. Also it looks like you can only get access to mobile services if you have the preview option enabled (I currently do not). That said, this does look like the best solution at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using a service, [Cotega](http://www.cotega.com) offers the ability to schedule execution of stored procedures from within SQL Azure.  You can read more about [how to schedule these jobs here](http://cotega.com/docs/sql_azure_scheduled_job).

Full disclosure, I work on this service.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger scheduled task running procedure directly from your application using, for example, Quartz.