# Store a temporary table and update it every hour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have never done this before, and I'm not sure if it is possible. Basically, I have a big query that takes around 1-2 minutes to run. What I'd like to do is:

- automatically execute and put result into a table every hour.
- My webpage will then query against the temporary table instead, which should be quicker.

I am looking for the steps to do this like. First, create a stored procedure. Second, setup somewhere to run the store procedure automatically. I'm not sure how to proceed — can you suggest how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL server supports running scheduled jobs. You can look here.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Also check this question, it should give you
a very good idea of the steps you need to take.

[How to run a stored procedure in sql server every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348863/how-to-run-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-every-hour)