# Update MySQL value after 1 Hour

Tags: mysql, null, mysql-event

How can I set the value of a column in mysql to either null or empty 1 hour after the value is set?

Comment: This sort of thing might typically be handled by an application sitting on top of a MySQL instance, rather than being handled directly from MySQL.  Can you give more context to your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's for a login token. User log's in, token is generated for application, after an hour, token expires but is still in mysql so the application stops working.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348863/how-to-run-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-every-hour

Comment: Why can't you just compare the expiry date against the current time?  By the way, if you're using Java, there is a truly awesome new thing called stateless session tokens.  They live outside the database and you never even have to hit your database when checking access tokens.

Comment: @Angelo this is MySQL, not Microsoft

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Mainly server resources because it would be referencing the db very often, and no, this is not in Java.

Comment: @CarterRoeser Look into database caching (e.g. Memcache).  You always have to check against the database, but that doesn't necessarily mean always hitting it.