# How to send scheduled email only if a data exists in database

Tags: php, sql-server, email, scheduled-tasks

What should i use if i need to make a scheduled email let us say every 12 midnight with query finding data that represents as a request for each approver. im using  sql server and php

Comment: You will need to write a php page that does the processing that you wish to be done.  Then you will need to set up a cron job on your server to trigger the php page when you want it to run.

Comment: @Joseph_J will it be the same with scheduled task on sql server? i think cron job is for linux/unix only (not sure)

Comment: I do not know. I use linux.  But I did a quick search and found this.  Looks like there are lots of resources to get you going.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348863/how-to-run-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-every-hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task involves couple of technologies:

1. cron or other scheduler to setup the execution of the job
2. PHP script that will read the data from the database and if found any relevant data send it to given email address or more
3. the database with stored data and probably the list of email recipients
4. you may want to log when were the emails sent and to whom etc.

Shall you have any difficulties? That's best for learning.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it plain and simple!

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question seems a little different than what is being asked in the title. If you're looking to conditionally send emails based on data being available or not in the database, the solution is pretty simple.

Setup a cron job that sends your email out every 12 midnight. Before running, the cron job should check a boolean flag that gets toggled `true` or `false` based on data being available in the database. To toggle the flag, make a GET request to your mail server (or whatever the METHOD and Endpoint your API offers for returning email count data as a response) using a function.

Using `Node`, you could write a very small module that takes care of this for you.

```
*index.js*

// Easy to use, *promise based*, NPM module for HTTP requests.
import axios from 'axios'

const domain = `your-mail-server.com`
const endpoint = `route/to/mail/api/`
const query = `list=mail`

const url = `https://${domain}/${endpoint}?${query1}`

const fetchMail = (bool) => {
    return axios.get(url)
        .then(res => res.body)
        .then(data => data.mail.count)
        .then(count => count !== 0 ? bool = true : bool = false)
        .catch(err => new Error(err));
}

const checkIfDataExistsInDatabase = () => {
    let mailExists
    return fetchMail(mailExists) ? {{ RUN_CRON_JOB }} : null
}

checkIfDataExistsInDatabase()
```

Just run `index.js` using `node` via the console.

```
node ./path/to/project/index.js
```

Make sure to setup a working `package.json` first by running:

```
npm init
```

or

```
yarn
```

Follow the basic setup prompts. Default values will work out of the box, so need pressure on having to change anything you may not understand right away.

Then include `axios` as a project dependency by running:

```
npm install axios
```

or

```
yarn add axios
```

Set the `start` command found in `scripts` to

```
"start": "node ./index.js"
```

Go back to your terminal and run:

```
npm run i
```

or

```
yarn
```

Then finally, run:

```
npm run start
```

or

```
yarn run start
```

Your app will run, running your cron job only if mail exists in the database.

You may want to add an additional Cron Job that runs this node app for you every midnight. Also, error logging and some kind of success/failure output would be a nice touch.

Cheers!

Comment: I used php. But now i have idea when i work with node apps. Thank you!

Comment: no worries. if you need help still (php or not), let me know. Most of the logic is still the same. Happy to help