# SQL Server: How to run a query every hour, and store results in a table? Replace them on update

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-agent

I have this taxing query that takes 5 minutes, and I'd like to have its results stored in a table, which will be queried by a backend.

Also, the table should be updated every hour and completely replace the table's content with the new data.

I found [this Server Agent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348863/how-to-run-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-every-hour), and from my understanding I should to this:

1. Create the results table.
2. Create a stored procedure that drops the results table data, runs the 5 min query, and inserts the new data.
3. Create the Server Agent job that runs the procedure in intervals.

**Is this the optimal way?**

Here is the query in question. It goes over a ton of rows, which I think is the main speed impactor.

```
WITH 
salesCTE AS (
    select
        concat(year(m.addate), '-', format(m.addate, 'MM')) AS ym,
        year(m.addate) as y,
        format(m.addate, 'MM') as m,
        sum(M.anvalue) as salesRev
    FROM tHE_Move m
    WHERE ( 
        RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '300'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '305'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '319'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '380'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '355'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '360'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '3X1'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '395'
    ) and m.adDate between '01.01.2014' and '01.01.2030'
    GROUP BY 
        concat(year(m.addate), '-', format(m.addate, 'MM')),
        year(m.addate),
        format(m.addate, 'MM')
),
retailCTE AS (
    select
        concat(year(m.addate), '-', format(m.addate, 'MM')) AS ym,
        year(m.addate) as y,
        format(m.addate, 'MM') as m,
        sum(M.anvalue) as retailRev
    FROM tHE_Move m
    where (
        RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '321'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '322'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '323'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '324'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '325'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '326'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '327'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '328'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '329'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '331'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '332'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '333'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '334'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '335'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '336'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '337'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '338'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '339'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '341'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '342'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '343'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '344'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '345'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '346'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '347'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '348'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '349'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '352'
        OR RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) = '353'
        ) and m.adDate between '01.01.2014' and '01.01.2030'
    GROUP BY 
        concat(year(m.addate), '-', format(m.addate, 'MM')),
        year(m.addate),
        format(m.addate, 'MM')
)
SELECT 
    s1.ym,
    s1.salesRev,
    (s1.salesRev / s2.salesRev - 1) * 100 salesDelta,
    r1.retailRev,
    (r1.retailRev / r2.retailRev - 1) * 100 retailDelta,
    s1.salesRev + r1.retailRev totalRev,
    ((s1.salesRev + r1.retailRev) / (s2.salesRev + r2.retailRev) - 1) * 100 totalDelta
FROM salesCTE s1
    left join salesCTE s2
        on s2.y = s1.y - 1 and s1.m = s2.m
    left join retailCTE r1
        on s1.ym = r1.ym
    left join retailCTE r2
        on r2.y = r1.y - 1 and r1.m = r2.m
order by s1.ym desc
```

Comment: That works, but is your actual question on how to improve the performance of your query? If so, we need said query to help you improve it.

Comment: Doesn't sound ideal unless you can be unavailable 8% of the time. You should have the new query results ready to go before dropping the old one

Comment: Either with the Server Agent solution, but usually I do it through a Scheduler Tool like BMC Control-M or similiar

Comment: @Larnu That should be a separate question I guess. I added the query.

Comment: @MartinSmith I added the query in question. So are you saying that I should simply reverse the actions i.e. have the query run, store the results in a temp table, and **then** drop the current data, and finally have it replaced?

Comment: `RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3)` is going to be costly in your `WHERE`. Have you considered having that information stored as a persisted computed column; that's probably indexed.

Comment: Also, I recommend against `FORMAT`. That function is a huge performance killer. I've had queries that ran in minutes run in seconds (or less) by getting rid of `FORMAT` and using `CONVERT`, `DATEPART`, `DATENAME` etc. I would personally replace `format(m.addate, 'MM')` with `RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(MONTH,m.addate)),2)`. It does look more complex, but it's far more performant.

Comment: A staging table - not a temp table. That can then replace the actual table. Either via a drop and rename or `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH`

Comment: `FORMAT` vs `CONVERT` [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df9a706db82a6a1f92dfdb4b663527da)

Comment: @Larnu Your suggestions dropped the time from 5 min to 30 sec. I didn't realize that the date and right/left parts impacted the query so much. I guess this changes things up, as I can now completely abandon the server agent approach and just use the query as the speed is good enough. Can you please write your suggestions as the answer so I can accept it? It didn't answer the question, but it solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment `FORMAT` is a massive performance hitter; and my massive i really do mean massive. Take this [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df9a706db82a6a1f92dfdb4b663527da) which uses `FORMAT` and `CONVERT` to change the value of a date. The query using `CONVERT` executes if 46ms (on db fiddle), yet the `FORMAT` query took 1218 ms! That's 26 times slower.

Changing `format(m.addate, 'MM')` to `RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,N-1,0))),2)` will have significant performance benefits on your query. Although the latter looks more complex, it will (as the fiddle shows) out perform `FORMAT` by a significant margin. *Honestly, I recommend never using `FORMAT`, Microsoft got things really wrong with that function.*

I do, also, however, suggest adding `RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3)` as a persisted column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE tHE_Move ADD {Meaningful Name} AS RIGHT(LEFT(M.acKey,5),3) PERSISTED;
```

Then you can also add that value to an index (new or existing) and it'll also greatly benefit the performance of your query; maybe pushing it to only a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although it wasn't about the scheduling, it eliminated the need for it. The 5 min query now takes 30 sec, which will be even less after some optimization.