# Alternative to using FORMAT in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a SELECT using the following in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT 
CAST(FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, date_time, 127), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ') AS NVARCHAR(20)) TimeStamp,
FROM myTable
```

This will result in a date formatted like `2019-03-15T13:25:19Z`

How can I achieve the same result using SQL Server 2008 R2 or older?

Comment: Don't use `FORMAT` in 2012+ either. it's an awful function.

Comment: I mean....why using `FORMAT` in your query at all?, just `CONVERT(varchar(20),date_time,127)` would do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this far more easily by just using `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(19),GETDATE(),127) + 'Z';
```

As I mentioned in my comment `FORMAT` is actually an awful function, it performs terribly. I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240958/sql-server-how-to-run-a-query-every-hour-and-store-results-in-a-table-replace/55241539#55241539) to another question earlier today on just how badly it does compared to a `CONVERT`. Don't just use this expression on your 2008- servers, replace the `FORMAT` expression on your 2012+ servers with this one too.

Comment: I always thought that functions like format, isnull, ... only peformed bad when used in the `where` clause. I learned something important today

Comment: **[`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** is a _function_ not an _expression. From docs: _Use the FORMAT function for locale-aware formatting of date/time and number values as strings._

Comment: `ISNULL`, and `FORMAT`, have performance implicates when in the `WHERE` clause as well @GuidoG, but that's due to SARGability. `FORMAT` specifically, however, is just an awful function. not sure how they managed it but it really is a huge performance killer.

Comment: @Sami yes, `FORMAT` is a function, but `CONVERT(varchar(19),GETDATE(),127) + 'Z'` is an expression.

Comment: I meant the `WHERE` clause, I updated my comment, sorry about that

Comment: @Larnu Nah, they are both functions, while `CONVERT() / CAST()` are functions can convert an _expression_ of one datatype to another.

Comment: @Sami `+ 'Z'` is not a function. within `CONVERT(varchar(19),GETDATE(),127) + 'Z'` there are 2 functions, `CONVERT`, and `GETDATE()`, however, the whole thing is an expression. My post references the expression the OP uses, as simply replacing `FORMAT` with `CONVERT` would not work; the entire expression needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(255), getdate(), 120), ' ', 'T') + 'Z'
```

Code `127` returns milliseconds, which you do not seem to want, so `120` seems more appropriate.