# How to execute stored procedure after every 5 seconds?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, timer

I am making a stored procedure, I want to make it auto executable after every 5 seconds.

I tried "WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';" but didn't fulfill my need.

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
```

I want one output result i.e one output table, not all previous results.

Comment: (1) This sounds like a really bad idea and the wrong way to accomplish some goal.  (2) Use SQL Server Agent to schedule jobs.

Comment: Gordon's first point is by _far_ the more important one. Take a step back and think about what you're trying to accomplish. Running a stored procedure every five seconds is almost certainly not the best solution. Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: Certainly the others are right, this is definitely an XY Problem and if you *think* you need to run an SP that frequently then something *else* is wrong. Note, however, that the most frequently an Agent task can be scheduled for is 30 seconds.

Comment: Using Agent, your job step can run a loop with WAITFOR DELAY, so the job step runs for a couple of minutes.  The schedule it to run continuously.  See eg: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76802/how-to-schedule-jobs-in-sql-server-2008-for-less-than-10-sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL Server Agent and create a job and schedule it to run every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql server agent to schedule jobs to run this stored procedure. Writing some logic in code would not be a good idea, as the code execution might time-out once the execution starts taking time (amount of data grows ).

Refer this : [How to run a stored procedure in sql server every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348863/how-to-run-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-every-hour)